# How do add fill an html dropdown list by items in an array in php

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

This is the HTML in a php file.

```
<select id="efHidden" style="width:80px;" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
     <option value="0">off</option>
     <option value="1">on</option>
</select>
```

and I have a php variable `$arr` having the required values to be shown

Comment: It is all these smaller things that .Net does for you that are the hard part in the transition from .Net to PHP. Keep at it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php $arr = array('off' => 0, 'on' => 1); ?>

<select>
    <?php 
       foreach($arr as $k => $v)
       {
           echo "<option value=\"$v\">$k</option>";
       }
    ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$arr = array('0' => 'off', '1' => 'on');
?>
<select id="efHidden" style="width:80px;" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
                        <?php foreach ($arr as $key=>$value) {?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $value; ?></option>
                        <?php } ?>
                       </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array('1' => 'Option One', '2' => 'Option Two', '3' => 'Option Three');
foreach($arr as &$item){ echo '<option value="'.$item[0].'">'.$item[1].'</option>'; }
```

Comment: -1 - $item will be a string, not an array, and also there's no need to access $item by reference.